# After running npm install, first I got an error

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, node-modules, npm-install, chakra-ui

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.0.0" from @ant-design/icons@4.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ant-design/icons
npm ERR!     @ant-design/icons@"^4.7.0" from antd@4.19.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/antd
npm ERR!       antd@"^4.19.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   115 more (@ant-design/react-slick, @chakra-ui/accordion, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typed
npm ERR!   react-typed@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-typed
npm ERR!     react-typed@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-02-21T06_41_01_848Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-02-21T06_41_01_848Z-debug-0.log

I tried to resolve it by uninstall all the version by using
npm uninstall @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react @emotion/styled  @testing-library/jest-dom @testing-library/react @testing-library/user-event antd axios babel-cli babel-preset-react-app bootstrap framer-motion nanoid phosphor-react react react-bootstrap react-dom react-redux react-router-dom  react-scripts react-typed redux redux-devtools-extension redux-thunk web-vitals

And i tried to re install it again
npm install @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react @emotion/styled  @testing-library/jest-dom @testing-library/react @testing-library/user-event antd axios babel-cli babel-preset-react-app bootstrap framer-motion nanoid phosphor-react react react-bootstrap react-dom react-redux react-router-dom  react-scripts react-typed redux redux-devtools-extension redux-thunk web-vitals
but still it does not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps below:

1. DELETE package.lock file locally and then do -
2. rm -r node_modules
3. npm cache clean --force
4. npm i // if this doesnt work do npm i --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).